# MySQL password changed every other day in windows?

Tags: mysql

Every morning when I check server status,I will find MySQL's password is changed:

```
mysql -uuser -ppassword
```

will report

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for
>   user 'user'@'localhost' (using
>   password: YES)

And then I restart server,and when it's up,MySQL will be back to normal.

It has now become a routinely job.

What can be the cause for this?

How can I know what's exactly happening to MySQL?

Here is the error log:

> 100122 10:11:16 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL
>   Server 5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal
>   shutdown
>
> 100122 10:11:16  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100122 10:11:18  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22939338 100122 10:11:18
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100122 10:12:40  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22939338 100122
>   10:12:42 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL) 100123 16:20:44 [Note]
>   D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal shutdown
>
> 100123 16:20:44  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100123 16:20:46  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22939832 100123 16:20:46
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100123 16:22:09  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22939832 100123
>   16:22:11 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL) 100125  9:18:59 [Note]
>   D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Normal shutdown
>
> 100125  9:18:59  InnoDB: Starting
>   shutdown... 100125  9:19:00  InnoDB:
>   Shutdown completed; log sequence
>   number 0 22941001 100125  9:19:00
>   [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: Shutdown complete
>
> 100125  9:20:22  InnoDB: Started; log
>   sequence number 0 22941001 100125 
>   9:20:25 [Note] D:\MySQL\MySQL Server
>   5.0\bin\mysqld-nt: ready for connections. Version:
>   '5.0.24-community-nt'  socket: '' 
>   port: 3306  MySQL Community Edition
>   (GPL)

Comment: The password isn't changing, otherwise a restart wouldn't help. However, there is certainly something amiss but I can't imagine what.

Comment: Something is wrong with your configuration and/or database. Better make sure you are not suffering some sort of database corruption.

Comment: How to identify that **something**?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't there supposed to be a space between the -u user?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connecting-disconnecting.html

```
mysql -u user -ppassword
```

Try that to see, or even better yet, try

```
mysql -u user -p
```

When prompted for the password type it in to see if you are getting the same error.

Comment: No,the space is optional.And I've tried both.